# How to load video fast like tiktok or Facebook in react native

Tags: android, react-native, exoplayer, react-native-video

I am trying to developed `VideoFeed` screen where user can view the number of video one by one.

I have used flatlist to render the video and used `react-native-video` library to play vide.

In android I have used `ExoPlayer` to play the video.

I am using HLS(.m3u8) url to play video, but it takes time to loading not too much but when I compare to TikTok or Facebook Story, then their's video load too fast.

How can I load the vide fast in my app.

I am using this bufferconfig to get least buffer for video but nothing get help me.

```
const bufferConfig = {
  minBufferMs: 100,
  maxBufferMs: 200,
  bufferForPlaybackMs: 100,
  bufferForPlaybackAfterRebufferMs: 100
};
```

I am stuck at this point from last couple of days.

Please anyone helps me.

Comment: You should `pre-cache` the videos. If the user is watching video `1`, preload & cache the next `2/3` videos so that the loading can be decreased. ExoPlayer has support for this via a `CacheWriter`.

Comment: you need to cache the videos based on current index also you will need to clear previous cache other wise your application will 100 percent crash since flatlist renders a new object evertime,i would also recommend you to use recyclelistview

Comment: if you models doesn't support caching you should download the videos into cache

Comment: Guys @DarShan , Abd, Is there any proper way to cache video in react native.  As I am using HLS and default caching system not support HLS video